# Multiple condition find and Replace

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to this forum and to Excel VBA. I have learnt a little by playing with VBA for sometime. But now I am stuck in this little problem which I am sure the Excel Guru’s here would be in a position to help me. Any help on this would be really appreciated . Below is my Problem

**Summary:**

I have a spreadsheet with values in Columns `A:F`
I want to find and replace values in Column `C` with Hex depending on the Value in Column `C` and Column `A`.

**Example:**

If Column `A = 1` and Column `C = General` then replace `General` with `0x0001`

But if Column `A = 2` and Column `C = General` then replace `General` with `0x0002`

**My code:**

`Columns("C").Replace What:=" General", Replacement:=" 0x0001", LookAt:=xlWhole, _SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _ReplaceFormat:=False`

**Problem:**

The code I currently have only looks at the values in Column `C` so changes every `General` to `0x0001`.

Answer (score 2):

If you start with:

[image]

Running this macro:

```
Sub Changes()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To N
        v1 = Cells(i, 1).Value
        v3 = Cells(i, 3).Value
        If v1 = 1 And v3 = "General" Then Cells(i, 3).Value = "0x0001"
        If v1 = 2 And v3 = "General" Then Cells(i, 3).Value = "0x0002"
    Next i
End Sub
```

Will produce:

[image]

Comment: This seems to meet my need tonight except that I will need to do it for all the worksheets on the work book at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @garys-student 's answer, I'd like to say that the "Case" method makes it easier for larger decision trees, e.g:

```
Sub Changes()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To N
        v1 = Cells(i, 1).Value
        v3 = Cells(i, 3).Value
        Select Case v1
            Case 1
                Select Case v3
                    Case "General"
                        Cells(i, 3).Value = "0x0001"
                    Case Else
                End Select
            Case 2
                Select Case v3
                    Case "General"
                        Cells(i, 3).Value = "0x0002"
                    Case Else
                End Select
            Case Else
        End Select
    Next i
End Sub
```

The "Select Case v1" goes in lieu of "If v1=" and then the "Case 1" completes it to "If v1=1".

Answer (score 1):

I would use a combination of If and Case, the V3 test only has one possible trigger, no need to case that.

```
Sub Changes()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To N
        v1 = Cells(i, 1).Value
        v3 = Cells(i, 3).Value
        If v3 = "General" Then
            Select Case v1
                Case 1
                    Cells(i, 3).Value = "0x0001"
                Case 2
                    Cells(i, 3).Value = "0x0002"
                Case Else
            End Select
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```